# jQuery Event Keypress: Enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a combo box which has got values and i want to give the user to select the values when the `Enter` key pressed.

1. User can navigate through `Arrow` key
2. Select the value when user enters `Enter` key.

I have done this one :

```
$('#cmb_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_CustomerName select').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
     if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
       //Do something
         alert("Enter key Pressed");
     }
});
```

but is not giving alert when I press `Enter` key.

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Best Regards.

Comment: I don't think it's the problem you're having, but this is unnecessary with jQuery: `var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);` jQuery [normalizes the `which` value for you](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Comment: Try on `keyup`. From the jQuery docs: "_The keypress event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms._"

Comment: Pressing enter in some html input elements will cause the form to submit or at least the onsubmit to be triggered (Firefox will trigger the input type submit onclick as well). If this is the case you might want to use preventDefault on the event object: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: @HMR FYI no such behaviour in HTML5 on select tags: http://jsfiddle.net/CNad7/1/ and Anto the thing you want to achieve is already supported by default with select tag

Comment: @AspiringAqib it is not working that is the reason why the post is here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 <select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>     

 <script> 
 $('select').live('keypress',function(e){
     var p = e.which;
     if(p==13){
         alert('enter was pressed');
     }
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Okay this one seems to be working, now i want to restrict the `Enter` option when a particular element is clicked in my case it is Combo box`select`

Comment: i have few combo boxes, each one does its own functionality, how to trigger this for particular combo box

Comment: use their id. each combo box you put a unique id then change the script to $('#combo_id').live('keypress',function(e){

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23484/discussion-between-anto-and-cathy)

Comment: live is deprecated. Use on instead

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
$('#cmb_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_CustomerName select').keypress(function(event){

        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if(keycode == '13'){
            alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox');  
        }
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post the form when the user presses enter you could also use a submit button which has this behaviour as a default.

If you don't want to post the form but do have a submit button, this might catch the key event and doesn't propagate.So remove any submit-button.

To restrict the event to an object use:

```
if (e.target == document.getElementById('element-id'))
```

or jquery

```
if (this == $('#element-id').get(0))
```

Your code would look something like this:

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(e) 
    {
    // Use 'this' or 'e.target' (whithout quotes)
    if (this == $('#cmb_CIMtrek_DailyshipCo_CustomerName select').get(0))
        {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(code == 13)
            { //Enter keycode
            //Do something
            alert("Enter key Pressed");
            }
        }
    // Stop the event from triggering anything else
    e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Comment: Using live() is deprecated in favour of on() e.g.: $("#id").on("keypress", function(event){ alert('message'); });

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```html
<!html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Bodega</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
      <option value="despacho">Despacho</option>
      <option value="ventas">Ventas</option>
    </select>
</div>

 <script>
     $('#exampleFormControlSelect1').on('keypress',function(e){
         var p = e.which;
         if(p==13){
             alert('enter was pressed');
         }
     });
 </script>
```